# Issue with toolbar layout, each tab is stacking on top of each other

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to get a tool bar working but the first 3 tab buttons keep writing on top of each other. 
Each tab gets display on top of one another on the left hand side of the screen.

I would like each tab button to fill and take up its on unique space.

How do I get the toolbar to display 3 individual tabs that span horizontally across the screen at equal size?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import "../controls" as Controls



Page{
    anchors.fill: parent
header: ToolBar{
    Material.background: "green"
    TabButton {
                id: tab1
             width: parent.width/3
              text: qsTr("Asset")
              Image{
                  source: "../assets/clipboard.png"
              }
                onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./asset.qml"
          }
          TabButton {
              id:tab2
                    width: parent.width/3


              text: qsTr("Issue")
              Image{
                  source: "../assets/wrench.png"
              }
                onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./issue.qml"
          }
          TabButton {
                    width: parent.width/3

              id: tab3
              text: qsTr("Log")
              Image{
                  source: "../assets/cogs.png"
              }
              onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./log.qml"


           }

}


Rectangle{
     id: loader1
     Loader{

         width: pageApp.width

         source: qmlfile1
     }
       Component.onCompleted: {


           console.log(loader1.height)
           console.log(pageApp.height)
           console.log(tabBarApp.height)
       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add row layout and each tab button gets

```
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.fillWidth: true
```

which fills the tabs out to occupy all space it needs

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

import "../controls" as Controls



Page{
anchors.fill: parent
header: ToolBar{
    Material.background: "green"
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
    TabButton {
                id: tab1
             width: parent.width/3
             text: qsTr("Asset")
             Layout.fillHeight: true
             Layout.fillWidth: true

              Image{
                  source: "../assets/clipboard.png"
                   Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
              }
                onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./asset.qml"

          }
          TabButton {
              id:tab2
                    width: parent.width/3
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true


              text: qsTr("Issue")
              Image{
                  source: "../assets/wrench.png"
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
              }
                onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./issue.qml"
          }
          TabButton {
                    width: parent.width/3
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true

              id: tab3
              text: qsTr("Log")
              Image{
                  source: "../assets/cogs.png"
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
              }
              onClicked: qmlfile1 = "./log.qml"


           }
    }

}

// Add a Loader to load different samples.
// The sample Qml files can be found in the Samples folder
Rectangle{
     id: loader1
     Loader{

         width: pageApp.width

         source: qmlfile1
     }
       Component.onCompleted: {


           console.log(loader1.height)
           console.log(pageApp.height)
           console.log(tabBarApp.height)
       }
}
}
```